# How to focus on PrimeNG p-button

Tags: angular, focus, primeng

I have a form in Angular. On pressing Enter key I would like to focus on the next control. On `keyup.enter` event for each input I use the ref of the next input and call `focus()`. But this isn't working for `p-button`.

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6">
  <label>Address Line 1</label>
  <input #regAddressLine1 type="text" pInputText [readonly]="!editMode" formControlName="regAddressLine1" (keyup.enter)="regAddressLine2.focus()">
  <small class="p-invalid" *ngIf="f.regAddressLine1.invalid && f.regAddressLine1.touched">Required</small>
</div>
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6">
  <label>Address Line 2</label>
  <input #regAddressLine2 type="text" pInputText [readonly]="!editMode" formControlName="regAddressLine2" (keyup.enter)="save.focus()">
  <small class="p-invalid" *ngIf="f.regAddressLine2.invalid && f.regAddressLine2.touched">Required</small>
</div>
<div class="p-col-12 p-md-3">
  <p-button #save label="Save" styleClass="p-button-primary">
  </p-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `p-button` component doesn't have such method.

I would consider using attribute version of primeng button:

```
<button #save pButton label="Save" styleClass="p-button-primary" type="button"></button>
              ^^^^^^^^
```

This way `#save` template variable is referring to native HTMLButtonElement which has `focus()` method.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-button-demo-1dfhq9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**